# TextView not updated, and AlertDialog does not show up when called inside thread, even using RunOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, textview, android-alertdialog

First of all, I should say that I am a newbie on Java and Android programming. I am very experienced in C programming for embedded systems, but now I need to communicate one of my embedded projects with an Android app, in a very simple way. I am using one of those ESP8266, configured as default. Thus, it behaves as a basic telnet server. My microcontroller has to send a question (through a string, which is not constant) to my app, and receive a "Y" or "N" reply. I have tested it using a telnet client, and it is working fine. However, I want to have an app that pops up an alert dialog and/or show the message in a TextView element, and sends the reply after some button click. For this, I have adapted a telnet client code from:

http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/simple-android-chat-application-client.html

I have put everything in one single panel, and reduced the number of elements to a textview element and 4 buttons (connect, disconnect, yes, and no). I am using a fixed IP and port to connect the app to my laptop, which is running a telnet server (hercules). The connection is confirmed, and the YES and NO buttons are sending the correct messages. However, the question string never shows up at the TextView element. I have also added an AlertDialog to pop up, because I think it is more appropriate to the kind of app I am developing.

Notice that the testing of the message income happens inside a thread, and I am calling the TextView update and the AlertDialog show using runOnUiThread.

Here is the Java code (not optimized yet):

```js
package br.unicamp.smpci;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int SocketServerPORT = 80;
    final Context context = this;

    LinearLayout Panel;

    Button buttonConnect;
    TextView chatMsg;

    Button buttonSendYes;
    Button buttonSendNo;
    Button buttonDisconnect;

    String msgLog = "";

    ChatClientThread chatClientThread = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Panel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.panel);

        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
        chatMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatmsg);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);
        buttonDisconnect.setOnClickListener(buttonDisconnectOnClickListener);

        buttonSendYes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendYes);
        buttonSendYes.setOnClickListener(buttonSendYesOnClickListener);

        buttonSendNo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendNo);
        buttonSendNo.setOnClickListener(buttonSendNoOnClickListener);
    }

    
    OnClickListener buttonDisconnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(chatClientThread==null){
                return;
            }
            chatClientThread.disconnect();
        }

    };

    OnClickListener buttonSendYesOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(chatClientThread==null){
                return;
            }

            chatClientThread.sendMsg("Y" + "\n");
        }
    };

    OnClickListener buttonSendNoOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(chatClientThread==null){
                return;
            }

            chatClientThread.sendMsg("N" + "\n");
        }
    };

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String textAddress = "192.168.1.11";

            msgLog = "NO MESSAGES";
            chatMsg.setText(msgLog);


            chatClientThread = new ChatClientThread(
                    textAddress, SocketServerPORT);
            chatClientThread.start();
        }

    };


    private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;

        String msgToSend = "";
        boolean goOut = false;

        ChatClientThread(String address, int port) {
            dstAddress = address;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                while (!goOut) {
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                        msgLog = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                                chatMsg.invalidate();
                               
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        context);
                                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ALERT");
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setMessage(MsgLog)
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                if(chatClientThread==null){
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                                chatClientThread.sendMsg("Y" + "\n");
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                if (chatClientThread == null) {
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                                chatClientThread.sendMsg("N" + "\n");
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if(!msgToSend.equals("")){
                        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToSend);
                        dataOutputStream.flush();
                        msgToSend = "";
                    }
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //loginPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //chatPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
            }

        }

        private void sendMsg(String msg){
            msgToSend = msg;
        }

        private void disconnect(){
            goOut = true;
        }
    }

}
```

I have done extensive research on how to make sure that the UI thread updates my elements, and I am using the Show() method for the alertdialog, and invalidating the TextView element to force it to update. I have used debug, and I am sure that the instructions are being executed, but with no result on my app ( I am using a real device for debugging).

I have seen that maybe I could use AsyncTask for this purpose, but as a newbie I am facing difficulties to make the changes, and I believe that calling the updates with a runOnUiThread should do the work.

Can anyone explain why I cannot see my message, and maybe provide me a code correction?

Thanks in advance,

Antonio Quevedo

Comment: Instead of `DataInputStream` you should use an `InputStream` and read the raw `byte`s sent by the `microcontroller`, I think the problem is that your `microcontroller` doesn't send the data in a way that can be read using the `DataInputStream`'s `readUTF()` method.

Comment: @Titus, thanks for your contribution, I will implement that in my program. Actually the microcontroller sends not a single byte, but a message string. Anyway, I have also tried to comment out the 'readUTF()' method, and printing a constant string, just to see if the TextView would update and some AlertDialog would pop up, and it did not work either.

Comment: One more thing,  when I debug the code, the program goes through the instructions, so my app is recognizing something being received, and it should at least update my `TextView` and my `AlertDialog` with that fixed message I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Maybe that is because `dataInputStream.available() > 0`  is never `true`, also, you're creating the dialogue inside the `while` loop, which mean that you can end up with multiple dialogues if the data is not read all at once.

Comment: @Titus, I am aware of the problems I will have with the input stream, and I will deal with them right after I get my dialogue to work. I am sure that the `dataInputStream.available() > 0` test returned `true` because I debugged the program and execution has recognized the test as true right after I sent something from my telnet server. I used step-over button to go through instructions, and I am sure that the `TextView` and `AlertDialog` elements were respectively updated and created/called, but with no response at my testing device.

Comment: I have the same problem recently, I use Log and can see the logging, but my textview won't update. Only until the end of thread, it will update for one time. Do you found the solution?